# Unable to start Stanford's CS106A Eclipse version - "Unable to access jarfile startup.jar" on Mac 10.6

Tags: eclipse, macos, osx-snow-leopard, karel

I've been trying to do the Stanford CS106A course through iTunesU, but I keep running into problems with Eclipse. I tried getting Stanford's custom version with Karel, but that kept giving the "unable to access jarfile startup.jar" error. I even tried getting a current version and trying the instructions on http://www.freesoftwaremagazine.com/articles/getting_stanfords_karel_robot_run_debians_eclipse, but that threw null pointer exceptions when I tried to run a programming assignment.

I'm not sure what information to give, but I'm running Mac OS 10.6.8 (64-bit, I think?), and my Java version is 1.6.0_22.

Any help you can give me would be greatly appreciated. I've got algorithms in my head, and I need to get them out! :)

Comment: What *exactly* are you trying to do, and what happened? As in, "I'm trying to do X. I did a,b,c and then d happened".

Comment: I downloaded Eclipse from Stanford's CS106A website, using the link for the Mac version. I unzipped the .zip file, then moved the eclipse directory (created when I unzipped) to the Applications folder (according to the installation instructions given for the course). I double-clicked the eclipse alias (the one with a shell script icon) in the eclipse directory, which should have started eclipse once the shell script ran. The shell script ran, but gave the error "Unable to access jarfile startup.jar". I've read that that can happen if startup.jar isn't in the directory, but it was there.

Comment: Did you try running Eclipse.app instead of the shell script alias?

Comment: Actually, I found out what the problem was. I was downloading from http://see.stanford.edu/see/materials/icspmcs106a/software.aspx, which I was given by iTunesU (and you'd be given by their Stanford Everywhere initiative), but the good version is at http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs106a/software.html. It's working fine now. Hope this helps anyone else with that problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct download link for the Eclipse package recommended by the course is actually via the class page here: http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs106a/

The software link is in the sidebar, but it uses frames so it's difficult to link directly. Here's the software page without the navigation:
http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs106a/software/

Comment: I try to use the above links and I get redirected to https://weblogin.stanford.edu/login/... which is looking for a login (which I don't have of course) -- seems I can't get to the good version of Stanford Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and had followed an older handout that pointed me to an older version of eclipse, I think pre OSX Tiger that will never work.  Thanks for the tip pointing me to the right location, I downloaded it from http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs106a/ and it worked right away.  Thanks becw

For those that are interested, this is even working in MAC OSX 10.10.1

Comment: Look under Resources  second line down where it says download eclipse.  Worked for me.